# if statements in a GSP in Grails

Tags: grails

I call an index method within a controller

```
def index() {
    childInstance = Child.get(params.id)

    if(childInstance){
        System.out.println("CHILD" + childInstance.firstname)

        def messages = currentUserTimeline()
            [profileMessages: messages,childInstance:childInstance]
    } else {
        def messages = currentUserTimeline()
            [profileMessages: messages]

        System.out.println("ALL")
    }
}
```

in the gsp page I have

```
${childInstance.firstname}
```

Which if i pass a childInstance this is fine but if I don't i get a 500 because of a null pointer is there a way I can do an if statement in a gsp so i can do this

```
if(childInstance){
   ${childInstance.firstname}
} else {
   All
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `g:if`, `g:elseif` and `g:else`:

```
<g:if test="${name == 'roberto'}">
    Hello Roberto!
</g:if>
<g:elseif test="${name == 'olga'}">
    Hello Olga!
</g:elseif>
<g:else>
    Hello unknown person!
</g:else>
```

Answer (score 6):

A more concise solution than `<g:if>` is to use the safe-dereference operator `?`

```
${childInstance?.firstName}
```

will display the first name if `childInstance` is not null and display nothing if it is null.

Answer (score 3):

```
<g:if test="${ childInstance }">
    ${ childInstance.firstName }
</g:if>
```